# D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain slow

Tags: directx, directx-11

I've been lately bother by a slow startup of my d3d11 app, so I started investigating and found that the culprit is D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain. This single call takes roughly 1.5 seconds. That seems crazy slow to me. Is this also your experience?

This is the setup code:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swap_chain_desc = {};

swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.Width = window->window_width;
swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.Height = window->window_height;
swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
swap_chain_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swap_chain_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
swap_chain_desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swap_chain_desc.BufferCount = 2;
swap_chain_desc.OutputWindow = window->window_handle;
swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
swap_chain_desc.Windowed = true;
swap_chain_desc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
swap_chain_desc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL feature_level = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL supported_feature_level;

UINT flags = 0;
#ifdef DEBUG
flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, flags, &feature_level, 1, D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                           &swap_chain_desc, &context.swapChain, &context.device, &supported_feature_level, &context.context);
```

Comment: ``D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain`` is a bit old-school. The modern best practice is to create the device and swapchain independently. This might also let you narrow down what part of the process is taking the time.Take a look at [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I tried it and it seems that the call to D3D11CreateDevice takes majority of the time.

Comment: If you don't do it with ``D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG``, is it any faster?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Try using the pattern ``ID3D11Device`` -> ``IDXGIDevice`` -> ``IDXGIAdapter`` from the blog post above and dump out the content you get back from ``adaper->GetDesc`` (i.e. ``VendorId``, ``DeviceId``, ``Description``). Might tell you more about what device is actually coming back.

Comment: I've tried that and the device is the one I'd expect - GeForce 1080GTX

Answer (score 0):

First, you should consider `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` deprecated, the device should be create separately, and you have a few variant of swap chain creation based on what your application is (hwnd vs core window for ex).

There is no justification to a slow device creation, but past experience with a slow device creation where due to d3d hooking from application like Steam. The easiest way to confirm is to take a profiling capture of your initialization and look at the involved callstacks and DLLs, child of the device creation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried calling `D3D11CreateDevice` instead, but as I've mentioned in the comments just below my original post, it doesn't help at all. I tried profiling, and it seems that calls to nvwgf2umx.dll take the huge chunk of the time - quick google search revealed that this is indeed d3d11 driver, so I guess nothing suspicious going on here.